# on_enter firing before screen is entered when using nested ScreenManager in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm having an issue with using a ScreenManager within a ScreenManager where the `on_enter` event is being triggered on the first screen in the nested ScreenManager before the screen is visible. This is an issue for me as there's some blocking code that's triggering on the launch of the script and causing unwelcome delays.

I've recreated the setup with the following code:

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from time import sleep

class NestedScreen(Screen):
    scrname = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NestedScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.scrname = kwargs["scname"]
        self.nest_scrmgr = self.ids.nest_scrmgr
        self.nest_scr_list = []
        self.nest_scr_id = 0
        for s in range(4):
            scr_name = "Nest-{}".format(s)
            d = NestedDummyScreen(scname=scr_name, name=scr_name)
            self.nest_scrmgr.add_widget(d)
            self.nest_scr_list.append(scr_name)

    def previous(self):
        self.nest_scr_id = (self.nest_scr_id - 1) % len(self.nest_scr_list)
        self.nest_scrmgr.current = self.nest_scr_list[self.nest_scr_id]

    def next(self):
        self.nest_scr_id = (self.nest_scr_id + 1) % len(self.nest_scr_list)
        self.nest_scrmgr.current = self.nest_scr_list[self.nest_scr_id]

    def on_enter(self):
        print "Nested screen on_enter event"
        print "Entering {}".format(self.name)

class NestedDummyScreen(Screen):
    scrname = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NestedDummyScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.scrname = kwargs["scname"]
        self.running = False

    def on_enter(self):
        print "Entering nested screen #{}".format(self.name)
        if not self.running:
            print "Sleep 2..."
            sleep(2)
            self.running = True

class DummyScreen(Screen):
    scrname = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(DummyScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.scrname = kwargs["scname"]

    def on_enter(self):
        print "Entering screen #{}".format(self.name)

class TestScreenBase(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestScreenBase, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.scrmgr = self.ids.test_scrmgr
        self.scr_list = []
        self.scr_id = 0
        for s in range(4):
            scr_name = str(s)
            d = DummyScreen(scname=scr_name, name=scr_name)
            self.scrmgr.add_widget(d)
            self.scr_list.append(scr_name)
        n = NestedScreen(scname="NestedScreen", name="NestedScreen")
        self.scrmgr.add_widget(n)
        self.scr_list.append("NestedScreen")

    def previous(self):
        self.scr_id = (self.scr_id - 1) % len(self.scr_list)
        self.scrmgr.current = self.scr_list[self.scr_id]

    def next(self):
        self.scr_id = (self.scr_id + 1) % len(self.scr_list)
        self.scrmgr.current = self.scr_list[self.scr_id]

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (800,480)
        return TestScreenBase()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

test.kv

```
<TestScreenBase>
    Button:
        size: 50, root.height
        size_hint: None, None
        pos: 0, 0
        text: "<"
        on_press: root.previous()

    Button:
        size: 50, root.height
        size_hint: None, None
        pos: root.width - 50, 0
        text: ">"
        on_press: root.next()

    ScreenManager:
        id: test_scrmgr

<DummyScreen>
    Label:
        text: "This is screen #{}".format(root.scrname)

<NestedDummyScreen>
    Label:
        text: "This is nested screen #{}".format(root.scrname)

<NestedScreen>
    FloatLayout:

        Button:
            size: root.width, 50
            size_hint: None, None
            pos: 0, 0
            text: "\/"
            on_press: root.previous()

        Button:
            size: root.width, 50
            size_hint: None, None
            pos: 0, root.height - 50
            text: "^"
            on_press: root.next()

        ScreenManager:
            id: nest_scrmgr
```

When the script is run, the following lines are printed immediately to the console:

```
Entering screen #0
Entering nested screen #Nest-0
Sleep 2...
```

The first line is fine, but I wasn't expecting the next two lines.

My guess would be that the `on_enter` event is triggered on the current Screen in the ScreenManager instance without having any regard as to whether that ScreenManager is, itself, visible.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Happy to report as a bug if appropriate.

Comment: If the on_enter method appears to be executing too early(before the screen itself appears), maybe you could instead use on_enter to schedule another method for after the screen appears, with Clock.schedule_once for instance. Just a thought, as a possible workaround.. Sorry if I've misunderstood

Comment: Yes, I had had a similar thought. I can get round the problem by having the nested screen manager only add screens when its own on_enter event is triggered (and set a flag so this only happens once).